# Python - decode ('utf-8') issue

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am very new to Python.Please help me fix this issue.

I am trying to get the revenue from the link below :

https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kFFsWYyPEqvM8AeF7Y2IDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=adp+revenue&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMkozijTUskot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrYpSy1LzSlMBIRiSrDMAAAA&spf=1500270991898

**I am using below commands :**

import re

import urllib.request

data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

data1=data.decode("utf-8")

**Issue :**

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
>   10798: invalid start byte

Comment: Are you sure it is utf8 encoded?

Comment: `print(type(data))` show what? Can I also assume this is python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better with requests:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_r...."
req = requests.get(url)
req.encoding = "utf-8"
data = req.text
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of downloading the specific URL given in the question, is HTML code. I was able to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the page after using the following Python code to get the data:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kFFsWYyPEqvM8AeF7Y2IDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=adp+revenue&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMkozijTUskot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrYpSy1LzSlMBIRiSrDMAAAA&spf=1500270991898"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content.decode('utf-8', errors="replace")

print (data)
```

Please note that I used Python3 in my code example. The syntax for `print()` may vary a little.

Answer (score 0):

`0xa0` or in unicode notation U+00A0 is the character NO-BREAK SPACE. In UTF8 it is represented as `b'\xc2\xa0'`. If you find it as a raw byte it probably means that your input is not UTF8 encoded but Latin1 encoded.

A quick look on the linked page shows that it is indeed latin1 encoded - but I got a french version...

The rule when you are not sure of the exact convertion is to use the replace errors processing:

```
data1=data.decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
```

then, all offending characters are replaced with the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD) (displayed as �). If only few are found, that means the page contains erroneous characters, but if almost all non-ascii characters are replaced, then it means that the encoding is not UTF8. If is commonly Latin1 for west european languages, but your mileage may vary for other languages.