# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 12387

Tags: python, python-re

My Code:

```
import re

import urllib.request

url="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf="
stock=input("Enter your stock: ")  # Enter your stock: FB   
url=url+stock    
print(url) # https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=FB    
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()    
data1=data.decode("utf-8")
```

My Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in  position 12387: 
invalid start byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - decode ('utf-8') issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147351/python-decode-utf-8-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The data isn't UTF-8-encoded; it's ISO-8859-1.

```
>>> url="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=FB"
>>> d = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>> dict(d.getheaders())['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'
>>> data1 = d.read().decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: Note that `'iso-8859-1'` will work even if it's wrong, because it's the only encoding that defines a character for every possible byte value.  Good suggestion to look at the headers though.